# Error while importing 'tensorflow_federated' on Google Colab Tutorial

Tags: google-colaboratory, tensorflow-federated

I've been working on the tutorial for *Federated Learning for Image Classification*, and while running the tutorial code on Google colab its giving me error while importing *tensorflow_federated*

[Federated Learning for Image Classification](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification)

Code (getting error on line 4):

```
import collections
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_federated as tff

np.random.seed(0)

tff.federated_computation(lambda: 'Hello, World!')()
```

Error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-a23308ec3f7c> in <module>()
      3 import numpy as np
      4 import tensorflow as tf
----> 5 import tensorflow_federated as tff
      6 
      7 np.random.seed(0)

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/common_libs/structure.py in <module>()
    263 
    264 def to_odict(struct: Struct,
--> 265              recursive: bool = False) -> collections.OrderedDict[str, Any]:
    266   """Returns `struct` as an `OrderedDict`, if possible.
    267 

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

I've tried updating the python version to 3.9 (as mentioned in some of the fixes available) but it didn't work.

***Solved:***

I followed this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/issues/2748#issuecomment-1107437271) and installed the 0.20.0 version of *tensorflow-federated* which worked for me

```
!pip install --quiet tensorflow-federated==0.20.0
#!pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow-federated
!pip install --quiet --upgrade nest-asyncio

import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```